# Dynamically create a table in SQL based on python datafaframe columns and insert into SQL table from dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe, dynamic

I'm able to call API in python that retrieves nested JSON. When I flatten JSON into pandas dataframe, it has 350+ columns. Creating SQL table manually with 350 columns and then writing a insert values statement for all those 350+ columns is cumbersome

I want python to create a table dynamically in SQL based on that 350+ columns and be able to insert those rows from dataframe  into this newly created table in SQL.

Any help/code/guidance to do this  will be appreciated.

Comment: Why create the table manually? Why not use `DataFrame.to_sql()`?

Comment: Are you sure you want  flattened JSON as your data model in  MSSQL - I strongly doubt it.  Have you considered normalisation at all?